# How can I generate custom quarters of a year given 1st date of first quarter?

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

If I give `04-Mar-2019` as 1st day of 1st Quarter, I want start and end dates of all Quarters from `04-Mar-2019 to 03-Mar-2020`. How can I do this in Java?
Thanks in advance.

```
Input - 1st day of 1st Quarter (04-Mar-2019)
Output - 
             Q1 - 04-Mar-2019 to ....
             Q2 - 
             Q3 - 
             Q4 - ... to 03-Mar-2020
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Michael Yes, tried it myself. Posted below as answer.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

```
    LocalDate quarterStart = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MARCH, 4);
    for (int q = 1; q <= 4; q++) {
        System.out.println("Q" + q + " begins on " + quarterStart);
        quarterStart = quarterStart.plusMonths(3);
        System.out.println(" - ends on " + quarterStart.minusDays(1));
    }
```

This loop prints:

> ```
> Q1 begins on 2019-03-04
>  - ends on 2019-06-03
> Q2 begins on 2019-06-04
>  - ends on 2019-09-03
> Q3 begins on 2019-09-04
>  - ends on 2019-12-03
> Q4 begins on 2019-12-04
>  - ends on 2020-03-03
> ```

For very many purposes you don’t want to make the end dates explicit. Everyone knows that each quarter ends when the next quarter begins. So consider leaving out the second `System.out.println` call, it’s just redundant.

Be aware that you don’t want a quarter to start on the 29, 30 or 31 of a month, or strange things will happen when you hit a month that doesn’t have that many days.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , did it myself...

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String []args){

         Date date = new Date();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {


            Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            startDate.setTime(date);
            startDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, (i*3));

            Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            endDate.setTime(startDate.getTime());
            endDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
            endDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Start Date of Quarter "+ (i+1) + "  : " + new Date(startDate.getTime().getTime()));
            System.out.println("End Date of Quarter   "+ (i+1) + "  : "+ new Date(endDate.getTime().getTime()));
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        }

     }
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
Start Date of Quarter 1  : Thu Aug 08 04:08:33 GMT 2019
End Date of Quarter   1  : Thu Nov 07 04:08:33 GMT 2019

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Start Date of Quarter 2  : Fri Nov 08 04:08:33 GMT 2019
End Date of Quarter   2  : Fri Feb 07 04:08:33 GMT 2020

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Start Date of Quarter 3  : Sat Feb 08 04:08:33 GMT 2020
End Date of Quarter   3  : Thu May 07 04:08:33 GMT 2020

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Start Date of Quarter 4  : Fri May 08 04:08:33 GMT 2020
End Date of Quarter   4  : Fri Aug 07 04:08:33 GMT 2020

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

This code doesnt work as expected in startDate is initialized to 29th or 30th Nov. In this case, it messes up in Q2 due to less no. of days in Feb.

I am working in it. Basically , I need to decide end date of quarter based on start date of next quarter.